# Command not found in ssh but is in direcory

Tags: bash, ssh, command, hpc, guix

I am using an ssh account that connects to an external server, i have downloaded through guix some software like samtools and bedtools but when i try to use them in my directory it gives me this error:

```
-bash: samtools: command not found
```

In my direcory, however, there is the directry guix.profile and if I go into the bin folder of this, I have everything I downloaded.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IOyF.png)

Answer (score 0):

To run a file from the shell you need two things:

1. The shell must find the file

Being in the same directory does not enable the shell to find the file. You have to either supply an absolute or relative path the file, or have the directory in your PATH environment variable

In simplest terms this means instead of

```
$ samtools
```

try

```
$ ./samtools
```

The relative path tells the shell it wants that file

To run it from another directory, either use the whole absolute path, e.g. `/home/yourname/samtools` , or move the file into a directory that is on your $PATH

2. The file needs to be executable

If the file is not executable you will need

```
$ chmod +x ./samtools
```

Comment: quick answer :   ~/samtools

Comment: When I try with :
/home/yourname/samtools 

tells me that there is no file in the directory although with ./samtools it works

Comment: I also try with:
PATH=$PATH:~/home/hub_galli/mfrancesconi/.guix-profile/bin
export PATH
But it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is that "ssh" on Guix by default won't set all of those PATH components where stuff is installed.  I'm also currently trying to figure out a good resolution to this problem and wil post an answer once I've fully figured it out.  One work-around is to use something like "(extra-special-file "/bin/scp" (file-append openssh "/bin/scp"))" in your /etc/config.scm